# Pagination with Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, pagination, laravel-pagination

I am using a system of infinite scroll pagination with Laravel and Ajax. It works like:

- I load the first 10 results, simply using
  `Book::orderBy('created_at')->paginate(5);`
- Then, via Ajax I call to another function which must return the next 5 values. But I don't want the first 5 values, only the 5 new ones.

So, I am looking for something like:

```
    $shown=10;
    $showPerPage=5;
   //The function that I am looking for
    Book::orderBy('created_at')->paginateFrom(10,5)
```

This would load the five books after the number 10. I've seen `Paginator::make()`, but I has two problems: first, it requires all the existing values, so I have to ask the db for every result, which is not very efficient, and second, I cannot pass an array to that funcion because Laravel return an object when you use `->get()`.

Any idea how could I do it?

Comment: Could be something like this: Book::orderBy('created_at')->skip(5)->take(5)->get() ?

Comment: Wow, I guess it works perfect.

Comment: Good then let me know, I've edited this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could solve:

```
$shown=10;
$showPerPage=5;
Book::orderBy('created_at')->skip($shown)->take($showPerPage)->get();
```

Basically the `skip` method adds the `OFFSET` clause and the `take` adds the `LIMIT` one.

**Source:** http://laravel.com/docs/queries